# Python script can't find dependencies when running from java code

Tags: java, python, linux, scripting

I got server which is starting process with python script and when it is running I got error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "save_boxes.py", line 2, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: No module named cv2
```

In fact I got opencv2 installed and script is working when I run it from terminal, have no ideas how to fix it, appreciate any advices, thank you!

The code Im running the script is:

```
 Process process;
            try {
                final char dm = (char) 34;
                ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("./runC.sh", "myArg1", "myArg2");
                Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
                env.put("VAR1", "myValue");
                env.remove("OTHERVAR");
                env.put("VAR2", env.get("VAR1") + "suffix");
                pb.directory(new File("/home/user/IdeaProjects/MyServer/"));
                process = pb.start();
        
                int exitCode = process.waitFor();
                if (exitCode != 0) {
                    throw new IOException("Command exited with " + exitCode);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {System.out.println ("error message: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());}
```

The script code:

```
#!/bin/bash

python my_script.py
```

Comment: Are you sure `python` command is pointing to python 3 or whatever version you are using? Normally, the command `python` points to python 2 so you might have to use `python3` command to run python 3 interpreter instead.

Comment: when Im running from terminal "python" command is running ok, but I've tried change python to python3 in script and it worked, thanks a lot man, you may write an answer and I will accept it

Comment: can you show the output of "which python" run from terminal and run from script? When it is not the same output then you are running different versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `python3`. On most of the systems, `python` is a link to the Python 2 interpreter. :)